# Can't call concrete implementation method if instantiated through interface

Tags: java, interface

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.trimToSize();
```

Since `trimToSize()` appears only in `ArrayList`, and not in the `List` interface, is this one of the features lost if i instantiate to an `interface` instead of a concrete class?

Comment: If you have a few spare minutes you should read this [tutorial about upcasting and downcasting](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50451-upcasting-downcasting/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only call the methods provided by the type you're calling on. If you wanted to call the `trimToSize( )` method then you'd need to first cast `list` to `ArrayList`:

```
( (ArrayList) list ).trimToSize( );
```